# Mystery thriller movie in which antagonist tries to kill a busload of brain damaged children to get transplant for his/her own kid

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller, mystery

The movie is from 2000-2009. English (US).

It involves a lot of mystery and guessing. I remember a character showing another character a room full of antique items ALL of which are fake. Then there's a drawing of a 'fish' as the answer to one of the mysteries.

Finally the antagonist poses as a bus driver driving a bunch of mentally challenged kids to death,so that he can use their healthy organ for his/her sick kid.

Comment: Approximate year? Country\language? Recognizable actors? Where\when did you see it? (Pretty sure I know what you're after, but these would *really* help...)

Comment: 2000-2009. English(US). I saw it on my friend's laptop. Don't remember any of the actors :(
Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like [The Oxford Murders](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488604/combined) from 2008 with Elijah Wood and John Hurt.

> At Oxford University, a professor and a grad student work together to try to stop a potential series of murders seemingly linked by mathematical symbols.

At some point, a bus driver blows up a bus full of mentally challenged children whose organs he needs to save his daughter. And a drawing of a '[Jesus Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichthys)' figures into the plot. Here's the trailer:

Comment: I don't have enough reputations for my upvote to be publicly displayed. How do I thank you?! You saved me a lot of brainache!